# Sorting a dataframe by multiple columns

Tags: r

I wanted to sort a data frame while the team names in the "name" column stay with the ratings in the "ratings" column.  For example, ne has the highest rating of 13.62.  I need both "ne" and "13.62" to be sorted to the first position.  Here is some of my code:

```
x <-t(nfl_data)
y <- solve(x)
myfun = function(i) round( (1/13)*(sum(x[,i])) + mean(y[,i]), digits=2 )

ratings = numeric(32)
for (i in 1:32){
    ratings[i] = myfun(i)
}

teams <- c('ari','atl','bal','buf','car','chi','cin','cle','dal',
        'den','det','grn','hou','ind','jac','kc','mia','min','ne',
        'no','nyj','nyg','oak','phi','pit','sd','sea','sf','stl',
        'tb','tn','was')

df <- data.frame(teams,ratings)
df[with(df, order(teams, -ratings)), ]
```

Here is the sample output of df:

```
     teams ratings
 1    ari   -3.73
 2    atl    9.46
 3    bal    2.31
 4    buf   -5.46
 5    car   -0.69
 6    chi    7.57
 7    cin    6.69
 8    cle   -4.23
```

I get the same results if I try running the ordered data frame code.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simply sort by `ratings` (i.e. `df[with(df, order(ratings)), ]`).  The way you are doing it currently sorts into alphabetical order of `teams`

Comment: Use `arrange` from the `plyr` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort on ratings column

```
df[with(df, order(-ratings)), ]
```